# Is there any way to compare two consecutive elements of a std::set in c++?

Tags: c++, set

I am using Codeblocks-13.12 and language C++. I wanted to compare two consecutive elements of a set using iterator. But the compiler gave error. I tried that just as a guess because I didn't get any info to do this by enough googling. If it is possible to do, then it would be too great.

The problem statement that I am working on is simple. I have given an array. I have to print a single integer,the maximum number of elements such that the absolute difference between any two of the integers is <= 1. The answer must be >=2.

I have solved this problem 100% correctly using array and set. Comparing two values of set, which I couldn't do using set, I have done that part using array. But if this part could be done using the std::set, then it would be too amazing and advantageous.
My code using both set and array is -

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#define for0(i,n)          for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
#define inf                100000000
using namespace std;
int a[103];
map<int,int> mp;
set<int> st;
set<int>::iterator it;

int main()
{
    int n,maxi=-inf,x;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    for0(i,n) {scanf("%d",&a[i]);mp[a[i]]++;st.insert(a[i]);}
    if(sz(st)==1){ pf("%d\n",mp[a[0]]);return 0;}
    for (it=st.begin(); it!=st.end(); ++it)
    {
        if(mp[*it]>1) 
        {
            x=mp[*it];
            if(x>maxi) maxi=x;
        }
    }
    sort(a,a+n);
    for(int i=0;i<n-1;i++)
    {
        if(a[i]!=a[i+1] && a[i+1]-a[i]==1)
        {
            int x=mp[a[i]]+mp[a[i+1]];
            if(x>maxi) maxi=x;
        }
    }
    if(maxi==-inf) printf("0\n");
    else  printf("%d\n",maxi);
    return 0;
}
```

This code is the 100% correct solution. But I wished to do the array part using set- that is comparing two consecutive element. My tried code is -

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
#define for0(i,n)          for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
#define inf                100000000
using namespace std;
int a[103];
map<int,int> mp;
set<int> st;
set<int>::iterator it;

int main()
{
    int n,maxi=-inf,x;
    scanf("%d",&n);
    for0(i,n) {scanf("%d",&a[i]);mp[a[i]]++;st.insert(a[i]);}
    if(sz(st)==1){ pf("%d\n",mp[a[0]]);return 0;}
    for (it=st.begin(); it!=st.end(); ++it)
    {
        if(mp[*it]>1) 
        {
            x=mp[*it];
            if(x>maxi) maxi=x;
        }
        if(it + 1 != st.end() && *(it + 1)-*it==1) 
        { 
            x=mp[*it]+mp[*(it + 1)]; 
            if(x>maxi) maxi=x; 
        } 
    }
    if(maxi==-inf) printf("0\n");
    else  printf("%d\n",maxi);
    return 0;
}
```

All the code is same as above except I added inside the "for" loop of set-

```
if(it + 1 != st.end() && *(it + 1)-*it==1) 
{ 
    x=mp[*it]+mp[*(it + 1)]; 
    if(x>maxi) maxi=x; 
}
```

instead of the array part -

```
sort(a,a+n);
for(int i=0;i<n-1;i++)
{
    if(a[i]!=a[i+1] && a[i+1]-a[i]==1)
    {
        int x=mp[a[i]]+mp[a[i+1]];
        if(x>maxi) maxi=x;
    }
}
```

In the line consisting of " if(it + 1 != st.end() && *(it + 1)-*it==1) " -  here I am getting the error - "no match for operator+ in 'it + 1' ". So, this way is not correct. But I want to know that is there any way to do the described operation that I am trying to do using set? Please if anyone can help, it would be great.

Comment: It's unreadable. http://format.krzaq.cc/. Don't use MACRO like that...

Comment: Your use of iterators is invalid, and would not even compile.   Use `*it` to access the element corresponding to the iterator `it`, not `mp[*it]`.

Comment: This looks very strange: `if(mp[*it]>1) x=mp[*it];
        {
            if(x>maxi) maxi=x;
        }`

Comment: Off topic: [Why should I not #include <bits/stdc++.h>?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h) and [Why is “using namespace std” considered bad practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-bad-practice). Putting the two together is a really bad idea.

Comment: @Peter: If you look at the types of `mp` and `it`, the expression `mp[*it]` makes perfect sense.

Comment: @Peter: It's correct and logically works.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ : It's logical because actually in this line I am checking whether the set element indexed in the map mp is present how many times in the input array a[103]. And if so, then I am giving my required next steps.

Comment: @ user4581301 : Thanks for the info. I didn't know these two thing. Thanks.

Comment: @amp1590 But why using an extra scope block for `{ if(x>maxi) maxi=x; }`?? Can you elaborate why you did so please? Shouldn't that be `if(mp[*it]>1) { x=mp[*it]; if(x>maxi) maxi=x; }`?

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ : I am so sorry. I don't know how and when I did that !! It just totally make no sense !! It's a totally unintentional mistake. May be it occured while typing the question. Sorry for the interruption. I am editing it.

Answer (score 2):

Your problem in reduced form:

```
set<int> st;
set<int>::iterator it;
for (it=st.begin(); it!=st.end(); ++it)
{
    if(it + 1 != st.end() && *(it + 1)-*it==1) {  // << error
    //do something
    }
}
```

The compiler error `no match for operator+ in 'it + 1'` is self-explanatory. Instead you should use [next](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/next):

```
if(next(it) != st.end() && *(next(it))-*it==1)
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I didn't have totally any idea about "next". @Saurav

Comment: @amp1590 `std::set` and `std::map` provides bidirectional iterator. You can do `it + n` only for random access iterator.